# How to keep new updated input value while printing the html page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some input fields that get default values.

A user can change the values of the inputs.

Then, I try to print the html page (window.print()) with the updated values, BUT the print preview shows the old default values (i.e., the printed page doesn't show the new inputs' values).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: show the code here.

Comment: where are the default values stored?

Comment: Use [JS: beforeprint event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeprint_event) or [CSS: @media print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Media_types) to ensure the value is updated prior to printing.

Comment: @Daryll can you be more specific about what you mean by 'ensure the value is updated'?

Comment: @TKoL If the DOM or CSS represent something other than what the user sees, it could be that CSS overrides this value on a specific viewport/device setting. It could also be that some JS API is doing some overlay or any number of things not changing the value attribute of the <input>. Without context, I believe none of us can provide any really directed guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked around a little bit and noticed [the npm site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-mobile-apps-client) successfully prints the entered value. I also noticed that the value in the input box gets live-updated in the html, which isn't how most input boxes work:

```
$('.classname').attr('value', newvalue);
```

If you have access to jquery, that code changes the value in the actual html, not just behind-the-scenes. Try that and see if it prints.

--- edit

I made a test html document with some inputs and I'm not having any trouble at all seeing changed input values with `window.print()`. You'll possibly need more context for your issue.

Comment: Thank TKoL, your solution is correct. The reason is that the window.print() makes a clone of the html when it is loaded. So when a user makes a change on inputs - the printing will not get the new values.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an onChangeListener, which can print your value.
E.g.

```
function onChangeHandler(val) {
    console.log(val);
}
```

And your input

```
<input type='text' value='myDefaultValue' onchange='onChangeHandler(this.value)' id='exampleInput' />
```

Comment: Michael thanks for you answer. I didnt mean print as console.log but actually printing a page (or a specific div content).

Comment: You can do this inside the function. console.log() was an example